# Can I play Dragon Age 2 without playing Dragon Age Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth completing Dragon Age Origins before playing Dragon Age 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22393/is-it-worth-completing-dragon-age-origins-before-playing-dragon-age-2)

I have played about 3 hours of Dragon Age Origins before I decided that I didn't like it. I read some reviews of Dragon Age 2 and thought that I would give it a shot.

I'm well aware of the internet's preference for DAO to DA2, but my personal preference is for small scale, self contained stories about people and relationships over what is in my opinion boring shounen save the world quests.

Is there something I can do to get up to speed on the events of DA:O so that I feel connected to the world going into DA2. I'm looking for some kind of extensive summary / fanfiction kind of thing, or will DA2 provide everything that's needed?

Thanks.

Edit:

Err how is this a duplicate? THere are no links to any references to any fanfiction on the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I last played DA2 but from what I remember there are only a few passing comments about what happened in the first game. You should be able to enjoy DA2 without playing DAO in my opinion.

And you can get a quick synopsis of the first game on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Origins#Synopsis)